# How can I make a command block say a formatted player's inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a command block say a player's inventory items.
I tried `/say data get entity @p Inventory` But it didn't work.

Also, is there a way I can format the output so it will be like:

```
[64] Diamond Ores
[16] Ender Pearls
```